# Unable to open fstream when specifying an absolute path

Tags: c++, fstream

I know this is rather laughable, but I can't seem to get simple C++ ofstream code to work.  Can you please tell me what could possibly be wrong with the following code:

```
    #include <fstream>

    ...

    ofstream File("C:\temp.txt");

    if(File)
       File << "lolwtf";
```

Opening the ofstream fails whenever I specify an absolute path.  Relative paths seems to work with no issues.   I'm really uncertain as to what the issue is here.

Comment: Oh, apparently 'C:\' is not accepted as a valid path.  This is rather unfortunate, as I am trying to write to a path specified by the TEMP environment variable.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It's in `std::`, if that's what you mean. You need to let us know what you mean by "it doesn't work". Compile errors? Run-time errors? Wrong output?

Comment: Apologies.  The main issue is that it refuses to open the file when I specify an absolute path including a drive letter.  Original question will be updated shortly.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the problem is escaping the backslash. But should you be making an assumption as to where the environment variable TEMP points? It would be safer to use Win32 API GetTempPath() or GetTempFileName()?

Comment: BTW, this problem is covered by C++ FAQ Lite 
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.16 
I encourage you to read the entire FAQ, you will learn a lot.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your path is invalid:

```
"C:\temp.txt"
```

The `\` is escaping the "t" as a horizontal tab character, so the path value ends up as:

```
"C:    emp.txt"
```

What you want is:

```
"C:\\temp.txt"
```

or

```
"C:/temp.txt"
```

Comment: I have done this mistake often in scripted languages and it comes back and says invalid path "blah" - with the escaped character disappearing immediately making me aware of the error.

Comment: This is the issue.  I was trying to get the Windows environment variable PATH, which was coming back with non-escaped slashes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in your string, you are not escaping the backslash.

```
 ofstream File("C:\\temp.txt");
```

Comment: @Ed: File isn't a pointer, but stream objects derived from basic_ios have an operator void*(), which returns a null pointer if fail() would return true, otherwise some non-null pointer is returned. This is how 'if(File)' works. (But you're right about having to escape the backslash.)

Comment: Ahh, ok, thanks.  I should have made sure of that before I posted.

Answer (score 8):

Even though Windows people seem to prefer the non-standard '\' character as a path separator, the standard '/' works perfectly and avoids annoying problems like this.

So, my advice is to stick to forward slashes...

```
std::ofstream File("C:/temp.txt");
```

Comment: non-standard?  I wasn't aware that the path separator was standardized.

Comment: Name a platform in common use today where '/' is not a valid path separator. VMS maybe?